# If URL variable equals ID than addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Surely there is a smarter way to arrange the following Javascript. I have a GET variable like 'engineering' or 'project delivery' but in the future it could be something different.

I then have links in the body that have id's that should correspond with the GET variable.

```
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("division=engineering") > -1) {
           jQuery( "a#engineering" ).addClass( "active" );
        }

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("division=project_delivery") > -1) {
           jQuery( "a#project_delivery" ).addClass( "active" );
        }

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("division=new_zealand") > -1) {
           jQuery( "a#new_zealand" ).addClass( "active" );
        }

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("division=infrastructure") > -1) {
           jQuery( "a#infrastructure" ).addClass( "active" );
        }
```

Can someone please help me out with a more efficient way to structure this jQuery?

Comment: how about jQuery("a#"+variablevalue).addClass('active');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
var key = window.location.href.match(/division=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/g)[0].replace(/^division=/, ''); 
if(key) jQuery( "a#" + key ).addClass( "active" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omitt repeatation by putting your get data into var,try something like this,

```
var div=<your get> // IE. engineering and etc
if(window.location.href.indexOf("division="+div) > -1) 
{
           jQuery( "a#"+div ).addClass( "active" );                
}
```

Note : I have not tested,so there can be minor bugs,code is for Idea purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(function (){
   var temp = location.pathname.split("division=")[1];
   jquery('a#' + temp).addClass('active');
}());
```

Comment: What happens with an URL like ... `http://server/doc.html?division=something&param2=value2`?

Comment: it was just an idea, not a thorough implementation of that, certainly there are other ways to get the value of get parameter from location.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

then just call

```
jquery('a#' + getParameterByName('division')).addClass('active');
```